# A group where every element is its own inverse

Tags: group-theory

Is it possible to find a group with more then say $30$ elements where $a*a=e$ for all $a \in G$ ?

I'm having trouble thinking about this problem, I don't even know where to start in thinking of a counterexample and can't really think of a theorem to prove it otherwise. The only group I know of where every element is its own inverse is $\mod 2$ under addition.

Comment: Think of $(\mathbb{Z}/2)^{2713}$ for instance...

Comment: All cases will be Abelian, but yes, you can make such groups of any size of the form $2^n.$

Comment: The standard answer is to do a cross product of mod 2.  You can make that as many elements as you want.  It might be harder to find any others or a set with anything other than $2^k $ elements.

Comment: That's because there aren't any others. @fleablood

Comment: I was leaving it as any exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: @fleablood Cauchy's theorem or Sylow's theorems ensures that all finite groups of this form have order $2^k$. I'm not sure about infinite groups, however. Maybe the group of binary sequences under addition modulo 2?

Comment: ...up to isomorphism, of course. It leads a secret nightlife as the group of all subsets of an $n$-element set with operation symmetric difference; $S_1 \circ S_2 = (S_1 \cup S_2) \setminus (S_1 \cap S_2)$.

Comment: @Anu A better way is to note that these groups are vector spaces over the field with $2$ elements. That removes the need for restriction to the finite case (assuming choice).